# Why will this simple maven project not build?

Tags: java, maven

I am attempting to follow the instructions to build a simple RESTful web service from the instructions found here: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/

However, whenever I try to build the project with "mvn clean package" I always get the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building RESTfulExample Maven Webapp
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, package]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] Deleting directory /home/username/RESTfulExample/target
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar': Cannot find parent: com.sun.jersey:jersey-project for project: null:jersey-server:bundle:null for project null:jersey-server:bundle:null
  com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.8

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  maven2-repository.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)

Path to dependency:
    1) com.mkyong.rest:RESTfulExample:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT



[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Mar 13 22:48:22 EDT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/212M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have completely deleted my .m2 directory multiple times, but this has not helped. From another StackOverflow article, I have removed the "repositories" section from the pom file, but that did not help either.

This is supposed to be a simple "Hello World" project, but it is driving me crazy.

[EDIT] Added the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>RESTfulExample</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RESTfulExample Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>RESTfulExample</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: This shows me `Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'c`  you have some kind of network/internet access issue (proxy?)..

Comment: can you show us you pom.xml? Did you declare groupId and artifactId correctly, because you have these `null` messages in `Cannot find parent: com.sun.jersey:jersey-project for project: null:jersey-server:bundle:null for project null:jersey-server:bundle:null`

Comment: BTW: Are you really using Maven 2.2.1 ? Maven 2 has been defined [EoL in Feb 2014](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html) ...I hope not. Please update to Maven 3.2.5 as soon as possible

Comment: I have added the pom.xml, and I am definitely using Apache Maven 2.2.1.

Comment: @Alexander I have added the pom.xml.

Comment: @khmarbaise I am definitely using Apache Maven 2.2.1, and I have no network issues.

Comment: From the linked tutorial: `Technologies and Tools used in this article: ... Maven 3.0.3` - Update to maven 3!

Comment: Wow ... I didn't even see that. Thank you for pointing it out. I was so focused on learning the technique, that I completely overlooked that "tidbit".